# Cast from long to same-sized int fails

Tags: c++, casting

I try to convert an array of `long` to an array of same-sized ints ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ygNVVR)):

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>

template<int> struct sized_int_ {};      
template<> struct sized_int_<8> { typedef int64_t type; };   
template<> struct sized_int_<4> { typedef int32_t type; };
typedef sized_int_<sizeof(long)>::type long_t;              

void funcA(int32_t* array, std::size_t s); // defined somewhere else
void funcA(int64_t* array, std::size_t s); // defined somewhere else

// technically illegal cast
void funcB(long* array, std::size_t s) {
    funcA(static_cast<long_t*>(array), s);
}

// memcpy
void funcC(long* array, std::size_t s) {
    long_t* tmp = new long_t[s];
    memcpy(tmp, array, s*sizeof(long_t));
    funcA(tmp, s);
    delete[] tmp;
}

int main() {
    long x[] = {2, 3};
    static_assert(sizeof(long_t)==sizeof(long), "Sizes don't match");
    funcB(x, 2);
    funcC(x, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

g++ happily accepts the code, but clang on MacOS doesn't (`error: static_cast from 'long *' to 'long_t *' (aka 'long long *') is not allowed`). `reinterpret_cast` works in both cases, but it also allows me to cast from `int32_t*` to `int64_t*`.

The correct way to allocate a temporary array and copy the data to it doesn't get optimized out by at least clang and gcc with `-O2`.

How can I cast `long*` to the corresponding `intX_t*` safely?

Comment: Don't.  Copy it instead.  A `long` and a `long long` are different types, even if they are the same size.

Comment: why do you detour via pointers instead of `static_cast<long_t>(x);` ?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 to keep the example short, in the full code I have an array of longs

Comment: @NathanOliver But the data has the same layout, so even though they are different types by name, they can be used interchangeably

Comment: @tstenner It does, but it technically doesn't have to and the standard says you can't alias a `long` as a `long long` since they are unrelated types.  Sure, on most platforms the code will "do the right thing", but it is Undefined Behavior and that is bad.

Comment: @NathanOliver But long is a signed integer type with a specific size. If it's neither 4 nor 8 bytes long, the above code will fail to compile so it's reasonably safe.

Comment: Do you really need the templates to demonstrate this? https://godbolt.org/z/dCitfv

Comment: @tstenner It should work just fine, you just have no guarantee.  You are in UB land and strange things can happen there.  Use it at your own risk is all I'm saying.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, because on other platforms (e.g. windows) long is 32 bits long whereas long long is 64 bits long

Comment: @TedLyngmo But you're right, in this specific example it doesn't matter

Comment: @tstenner: I think you miss the point. If you have an `long array[N]`, you use `long*`.  That works both on Windows and Mac. There's no need to use `int32_t*` or `int64_t*`. Both types are wrong, on both platforms.

Comment: @MSalters The problem is that on one platform `long` is 32bit on another it is 64 bit. If goal to have one strict size, only `int64_t`\`int32_t` can be used.but int64_t defined as long long on linux and windows, but as long on Mac (and some oldish PowerPc platforms as well). On some controller boardand similar `int` is 16 bit and `long long` is 32 :P

Comment: @MSalters So with a `long` array from one library and another library that accepts fixed sized int arrays there's no way to pass data from one library to the other even if `long` is an integer type?

Comment: @tstenner There is! don't use cast. `static_cast` is not legal in this case anyway, but `intX_t` are aliases, implicit cast applies  (btw, look at the template in boost library which does same thing you wanted to do here with requested size).

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: There's no guarantee that `long` is the alias of any `intX_t`. Also, `long long` cannot be 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I cast long to the corresponding intX_t safely?

You don't need to cast. The conversion is implicit:

```
long x = 2;
long_t y = x;
```

But you can use static cast if you want to be explicit:

```
long_t y = static_cast<long_t>(x);
```

---

The pointer trickery implies that you may want to deal with the object in-place. This of course requires that the types have the same representation, which is fairly reasonable assumption although not guaranteed. But even the assumption not technically sufficient for the indirection through `reinterpret_cast` to be well defined according to the standard.

You can technically reuse the storage by creating an object of desired type:

```
long_t temp = x;
long_t* reused_x = new(&x) long_t(temp);
```

After reusage, you can convert the pointer to `x` on the fly if you can't store the one returned by placement new by laundering. Note that laundering is not sufficient without the placement new above.

```
long_t* converted = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<long_t*>(&x));
```

Same can be done in a loop with arrays:

```
template<class T, class F> // types To and From
T* reuse_array(F* first, F* last, T* d_first) {
    for (F* ptr = first; ptr != last; ++d_first, (void) ++ptr) {
        T value = *ptr;
       ::new (ptr) T(value);
    }
   return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(first));
}
```

This can be done even with strctures using `std::memcpy` as long as they are trivially copyable and destructible. A reasonably good optimiser should [elide the copies](https://godbolt.org/z/X2A6Ro). Note that the lifetime of `x` has ended and may not be used anymore.

There is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html) to introduce `std::bless` into the language which should remove the need for explicit object creation in cases like this.

Comment: `std::bless`? Seriously? The `perl` in me sings with joy! :-D

Comment: "A reasonably good optimiser should elide the copies."

At least clang, gcc and icc don't.

Comment: MSVC 19.22 with `/Ox` also allocates extra memory and calls memcpy.

Comment: isn't `std::launder` meant for that?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie no, laundering doesn't create objects. Laundering would be needed to covert the address of x into correct type after the placement new if you cannot use the pointer returned by new directly. Such as when x is a member and you want to avoid storing the converted pointer as well.

Comment: @tstenner yeah, the memcpy elision probably only works when the size is known at compile time, so not with dynamic arrays unfortunately.

Comment: @tstenner but the placement new in a loop is elided, so you can use that.

Comment: @eerorika was actually thinking that, provided that's how launder was demonstrated.. well, unless object already was there

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking you don't need any casting at all and if there is no need in function wrapper, it's better to template it, as one of `intX_t` is an alias of one of integral types and overloading of function works due to implicit cast.